# Which mobile windows devices don't support AVX2

Tags: windows, mobile, avx, avx2

I understand that Intels AVX2 extension is on the market since 2011 and therefore it is pretty much standard in modern devices.

However, for some decision making we need to find out, roughly, the share of existing mobile windows devices which don't support AVX2 (nor its successor AVX-512).

It is rather well documented, which CPUs, Intel and AMD, actually support the extension. So that is not what I am asking for.

How do I find which mobile windows devices exist on the market, including recent years, that have processors which don't yet support the AVX2 instruction set?

Answer (score 1):

You're incorrect about the dates, and about being "pretty much standard", unfortunately.  It could have been by now if Intel hadn't disabled it for market-segmentation reasons in their low-end CPUs.  (To be slightly fair, that may have let them sell chips with defects in one half of a 256-bit execution unit, improving yields).

All AMD CPUs aimed at mobile/laptop use (not Geode), including low-power CPUs since Jaguar, have had AVX since Bulldozer.  Their low-power CPUs decode 256-bit instructions to two 128-bit uops, same as they did in Bulldozer-family and Zen1. (Which meant it wasn't always worth using in Bulldozer-family, but it wasn't a lot slower than carefully-tuned SSE, and sometimes still faster, and meant software had that useful baseline.  And 128-bit AVX instructions are great everywhere, often saving instructions by being 3 operand.)  Intel used the same decode into 2 halves strategy in Gracemont as the E-cores for Alder Lake, like they did for SSE in P6 CPUs before Core 2, like Pentium III and Pentium M.

---

**AVX was new in Sandy Bridge (2011) and Bulldozer (2011), AVX2 was new in Haswell (2013) and Excavator (2015).**

**Pentium/Celeron versions of Skylake / Coffee Lake** etc. (lower end than i3) **have AVX disabled**, along with AVX2/FMA/BMI1/2.  BMI1 and 2 include some instructions that use VEX encodings on general-purpose integer registers, which seems to indicate that Intel disables decoding of VEX prefixes entirely as part of binning a silicon chip for use in low-end SKUs.

The first Pentium/Celeron CPUs with AVX1/2/FMA are Ice Lake / Tiger Lake based.  There are currently Alder Lake based Pentiums with AVX2, like 2c4t (2 P cores) [Pentium Gold G7400](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/219435/intel-pentium-gold-g7400-processor-6m-cache-3-70-ghz.html) and [Pentium Gold 8505](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/226265/intel-pentium-gold-processor-8505-8m-cache-up-to-4-40-ghz-with-ipu.html) (mobile 1 P core, 4 E cores).  So 7xxx and 8xxx and higher Pentiums should have AVX1 / AVX2 / FMA, but earlier ones mostly not.  One of the latest without AVX is desktop [Pentium Gold G6405](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/201901/intel-pentium-gold-g6405-processor-4m-cache-4-10-ghz.html), 2c4t Comet Lake launched in Q1 2021.  (The mobile version, 6405U, launched in Q4'19). There's also an "Amber Lake Y" [Pentium Gold 6500Y](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/213357/intel-pentium-gold-6500y-processor-4m-cache-up-to-3-40-ghz.html) with AVX2, launched Q1'21.

---

**Low-power CPUs in the Silvermont family** (up to 2019's [Tremont](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/tremont)) don't support AVX at all.

These are common in "netbook" and low budget laptops, as well as low-power servers / NAS.   (The successor, Gracemont, has AVX1/2/FMA, so it can work as the E-cores in Alder Lake.)

These CPUs are badged as Pentium J-series and N-series.  For example, [Intel Pentium Processor N6415](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/207906/intel-pentium-processor-n6415-1-5m-cache-up-to-3-00-ghz.html) launched in 2021, with 4 cores, aimed at "PC/Client/Tablet" use cases.  These are [Elkheart Lake](https://www.anandtech.com/show/16102/intel-launches-10nm-atom-embedded-cpus-elkhart-lake-now-available) (Tremont cores), with only SSE4.2.

The "Atom" brand name is still used on server versions of these, including chips with 20 cores.